# Toggle element based on viewport & scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, viewport

I'm trying to toggle an element based on the viewport and scrolling.

By using `$(window).scroll(function()..` I can fire an event when the user scrolls but how do I check whether you're scrolled to the top in order to hide the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE the property is

```
document.body.scrollTop
```

and in standards-based browsers the property is

```
window.pageYOffset
```

Test for a value of 0 to hide your element.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. Thanks.

Found an article on the subject here as well: http://radumicu.info/blog/2010/02/20/animated-top-link-that-works-on-every-browser/